# How can I get invoke command to return an output to a variable?

Tags: multithreading, powershell, jobs, invoke-command

I'm trying to loop through an array of servers and run this test path command as a background thread. It needs to be a thread because I will be monitoring it for a time out and killing the thread if it exceeds that time out.

I cannot get a variable return value, nor do I know how I would have separate variables for multiple machines or if I'm passing the variables properly. In c# I would use a thread collection, but I can't seem to figure out the syntax for Powershell.

```
foreach ($server in $servers)
{
    Write-Host $server;

    $scriptBlock = 
    {
        $returnVal = Test-Path "\\$server\c$";
        return $returnVal;
    }
    $remoteReturnVal = Invoke-Command -ComputerName [Environment]::MachineName -ScriptBlock { $script } –AsJob;
}
```

Here is how I can do it in Powershell with c# (the below works)

```
$shareCheck = 
@'

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace powershellConsoleForm
{
    public class shares
    {
        public List<string> shareExists(List<string> servers, int timeOut)
        {
            List<string> returnValue = new List<string>();
            foreach (string server in servers)
            {
                string path = @"\\" + server + @"\c$";
                Func<bool> func = () => Directory.Exists(path);
                Task<bool> task = new Task<bool>(func);
                task.Start();
                if (task.Wait(timeOut))
                {
                    //return task.Value;
                    Console.Write(" ");
                    Console.Write("success " + task.Result);
                    Console.Write(" ");
                    returnValue.Add(server + "|" + task.Result.ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write("timeout");
                    returnValue.Add(server + "|timeout");
                }
            }
            Console.Write("Done");
            return returnValue;
        }
    }
}
'@

try
{
    $shareChecker = New-Object powershellConsoleForm.shares;
}
catch
{
    $assemblies = ("System", "System.Collections", "System.ComponentModel", "System.Data", "System.Drawing", "System.IO", "System.Linq", "System.Management.Automation", "System.Security", "System.Threading.Tasks", "System.Windows.Forms", "System.Threading", "System.Collections.Concurrent", "System.Security.Principal");
    Add-Type -TypeDefinition $shareCheck -ReferencedAssemblies $assemblies -Language CSharp
    $shareChecker = New-Object powershellConsoleForm.shares;
}

$servers = @("server1", "server2", "server3", "server4", "server5");
$timeOut = 11000;

[int] $counter = 0;
do
{
    $counter ++;
    Write-Host $counter;
    $shareAvailibilities = $shareChecker.shareExists($servers, $timeOut);
    foreach ($shareAvailibility in $shareAvailibilities)
    {
        Write-Host $shareAvailibility;
    }

    Write-Host " ";
    Write-Host " ";

    Sleep 5;
}while ($true)
```

Comment: Check your `-ScriptBlock` argument on Invoke-Command; it looks like you may have passed the wrong variable name.

Comment: `$script` != `$scriptBlock`. Passing parameters to `Invoke-Command` can be annoying. See [4Sysops](https://4sysops.com/archives/using-a-local-variable-in-a-remote-powershell-session/). I think it will return a job if you use `-AsJob`.

Comment: I'd be grateful if someone could convert my working c# code to powershell jobs so I could learn to better use powershell jobs

Answer (score 1):

First thing, Invoke-Command by defaults returns the output of the scriptblock. So your scriptblock could be something like `$ScriptBlock = {Test-Path "\\$server\c$"}`.

Then, there are several issues with your Invoke-Command line.

- Since you're using -AsJob, you don't need to assign output to a variable. You would access the results of your job with `Get-Job`.
- Then you could add `-JobName $server` so it's easier to view the results by server.
- Remove -ComputerName as it runs on localhost by default. As a side note, I personally like using `$env:COMPUTERNAME` instead as it's a bit easier on the eyes, and to access.
- You have wrapped your `$script` variable inside of a scriptblock, when it's already a script block. Remove the curly braces. But, since the command is so simple, it might make more sense to just keep the braces, and replace variable with the command.

here's a revised copy of your script, based on my adjustments (and a couple formatting tweaks):

```
foreach ($server in $servers) {
  Write-Host $server
  Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { Test-Path "\\$server\c$" } –AsJob -JobName $server
}
Get-Job
```

---

I was thinking about it, and since you're just running these on the local machine, it would make a lot more sense to just use Start-Job:

```
foreach ($server in $servers) {
  Write-Host $server
  Start-Job -Name $server -ScriptBlock { Test-Path "\\$server\c$" }
}
Get-Job
```

Then to get the results of the jobs themselves you can use Receive-Job. Either pipe Get-Job to Receive-Job, or access each one by name `Receive-Job -Name <servername>`

Comment: Op could also add  `Get-Job | Wait-Job -Timeout [int]` to accommodate the Timeout requirement.  Once exceeded they'll have to handle any jobs that are still running, for example; 
    `$jobs = Get-Job; 
     $jobs | Wait-Job -Timeout 30;
     $jobs | Where-Object { $_.State -match "Running" } | Stop-Job;
     $jobs | Receive-Job.`

Comment: This code below is my interpretation of what you suggested and it only outputs one of the return values and it's false and should be true? I don't understand why such a simple script is so complicated in Powershell, I could have written this 10 different ways in c#?

`foreach ($server in $servers) 
{
  Write-Host $server;
  Start-Job -Name $server -ScriptBlock { Test-Path "\\$server\c$" };
}

foreach ($server in $servers) 
{
 Receive-Job -Name $server;
}